# is the USA afraid of Venezuela?

Tags: armed-conflict, drugs, venezuela, vietnam

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venezuela#Petroleum_and_other_resources):

> Venezuela has the largest oil reserves, and the eighth largest natural
>   gas reserves in the world, and consistently ranks among the top ten
>   world crude oil producers.

but they are playing to "be a bad ass" same as Nord Korea and Iran.

a few days ago Trump talked about it:

[Trump Alarms Venezuela With Talk of a ‘Military Option’](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/08/12/world/americas/trump-venezuela-military.html?mcubz=3)

and Venezuela replies by doing:

[Venezuela stages military exercise to counter U.S. 'threat'](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-venezuela-usa-military-idUSKBN0MA0WN20150315)

but the exercises was just more than ridiculous only demonstrating that Venezuela has almos zero chance to even do some damage to USA troops...

and as you can see, they are involving a lot of elderly groups just as show off

[image]

my question is:

what is blocking the USA to bring some freedom to Venezuela, at the end that:

- will ends the communism franchise that is spreading like a decease in Latin america
- will bring better energy plans to USA since Venezuela has a lot of oil and Gas.
- the can defeat a [drug issue](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2009/07/18/AR2009071801785.html) they are aware of

or is some how america afraid to lose the war same as in Vietnam?

why they just dont do the same they did with Panama and the Drug-Dealer Noriega?

Comment: If the "soldier grandmother" Martinez fires that weapon, you have to take her to the hospital with broken bones.

Comment: @Peppo : if she shoots at you, you won't be able to drive her anywhere.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted. Shouldn't you add your thoughts for the downvotes?

Comment: "bring some freedom"? Is this a genuine question, or a bad joke? (Since you asked, @FrankCedeno.)

Comment: It's unclear how or why sending troops of young men to shoot at smiling old ladies would advance the cause of freedom.

Comment: Why, it's absolutely clear. The young men will shoot at those who oppress freedom, not at "smiling young ladies", don't give in to propaganda.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Invading another country costs a **lot** of:

- [Human lives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casualties_of_the_Iraq_War#Coalition_military_casualties) - and it's much higher in the invaded country, in modern war.
- [Money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_cost_of_the_Iraq_War)
- Political capital if the war is not uber-popular at home (citation: Vietnam, Iraq).
- International goodwill unless you are in super-rare circumstances (like first Gulf War).

As such, the cost/benefit ratio to USA of invading Venezuela is pretty low, even assuming invasion will succeed - which, as we again learn from Vietnam, isn't a guarantee.

This is compounded by the fact that Chavista rulers are still somewhat popular - a large minority (22% as of [this poll in 2017](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-venezuela-politics-idUSKBN1910SY)) still supports Maduro. You may recall how much PITA a small minority of Saddam supporting Sunnis gave USA in Iraq.

---

As an additional consideration, look at three last US Presidents:

- G.W.Bush: already swallowed more than his political capital could chew on with Iraq War. Venezuela wasn't anywhere near priority.
- Barack Obama: wasn't as ideologically opposed to Chavista regime as a Republican president would; and was an opponent of invasions as tool of politics (see his criticism of Iraq War).
- Donald Trump: Openly ran for Presidency on a platform of international non-interventionism and stopping to spend US money and lives on behalf of other countries.

None of them would be terribly interested in attacking Venezuela even if they weren't prevented by cost/benefit analysis above.

---

As bonus points, let's address your suggested benefits if this happened:

- > *will ends the communism franchise that is spreading like a decease in Latin america*

  This is debatable at best. Vietnam helped spread leftism in USA more than stopped the spread of communism world-wide. Iraq War helped grow Islamism, not stopped it. Heck, some anti-Maduro Venezuelians are likely to turn anti-US and join Maduro if we invade, out of understandable nationalist/patriotic sentiment.
- > *will bring better energy plans to USA since Venezuela has a lot of oil and Gas.*

  Not really. Venezuela wouldn't add all that much supply to hydrocarbon markets in the short term to affect oil prices, and by now, USA is close to being energy self-sufficient, especially given recent domestic political changes.
- > *the can defeat a drug issue they are aware of*

  We couldn't even do it in Mexico despite working with Mexican governments that were directly willing to ally with USA on the issue. What's the evidence we can do so in Venezuela?

Comment: Mexican cooperation might not be the best example since many of the problems are blamed on Mexican corruption, my region has serious locally made drug problems, and Afghanistan (even apparently the coalition favoring parts) still has opium poppies.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt - that's the point though. There's always some reason why that doesn't work - local corruption being one of them. If it didn't work in Mexico where the top federal government genuinely tried, there's zero chance it will work in Venezuela any better.